# Buffer before response.redirect in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Anyone know on how to do buffer before I proceed to `response.redirect` to another page?

Below is the sample code that I've done.

```
Dim msg = String.Format("<script language='javascript'>alert('Payment Success');</script>")
context.Response.Write(msg)
context.Response.Redirect("Index.aspx")
```

Comment: Do you need to message occur before redirection?

Comment: yes. I'll try to use code above but it seems like the alert part didn't appear, it skip to redirect part only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to do redirection in javascript.

```
Dim msg = String.Format("<script language='javascript'>alert('Payment Success');
 window.location.replace('Index.aspx'); </script>")
context.Response.Write(msg)
```

Alternatively you can use `window.location.href='Index.aspx'` (see [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093))